# dbWriteTable only writes 1 row of data.frame to MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, r, odbc, dbi

Starting in mid-March, dbWriteTable stopped working properly and now only write the first row of the data.frame into the MySQL table. After this occurred, I updated MySQL, MySQL Workbench, RStudio, R and all my R packages to latest versions, but no improvement.  Originally, I thought it occurred only when appending to database tables, but it also occurs when writing to newly created tables.

It does not produce an error message and dbWriteTable returns TRUE as if it was successful, but only one row had been written to the MySQL table.

### Session info

```
 devtools::session_info()
 - Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Los_Angeles         
 date     2020-04-14                  

 - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------

package     *  version    date       source     
- assertthat    0.2.1    2019-03-21  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
- backports     1.1.6    2020-04-05  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- bit           1.1-15.2 2020-02-10  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- bit64         0.9-7    2017-05-08  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- blob          1.2.1    2020-01-20  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- callr         3.4.3    2020-03-28  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- cli           2.0.2    2020-02-28  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- crayon        1.3.4    2017-09-16  CRAN (R 3.5.0)
- DBI         * 1.1.0    2019-12-15  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- desc          1.2.0    2018-05-01  CRAN (R 3.5.0)
- devtools      2.3.0    2020-04-10  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- digest        0.6.25   2020-02-23  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- ellipsis      0.3.0    2019-09-20  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- fansi         0.4.1    2020-01-08  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- fs            1.4.1    2020-04-04  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- glue          1.4.0    2020-04-03  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- hms           0.5.3    2020-01-08  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- magrittr      1.5      2014-11-22  CRAN (R 3.5.0)
- memoise       1.1.0    2017-04-21  CRAN (R 3.5.0)
- odbc        * 1.2.2    2020-01-10  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- pkgbuild      1.0.6    2019-10-09  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- pkgconfig     2.0.3    2019-09-22  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- pkgload       1.0.2    2018-10-29  CRAN (R 3.5.1)
- prettyunits   1.1.1    2020-01-24  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- processx      3.4.2    2020-02-09  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- ps            1.3.2    2020-02-13  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- R6            2.4.1    2019-11-12  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- Rcpp          1.0.4.6  2020-04-09  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- remotes       2.1.1    2020-02-15  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- rlang         0.4.5    2020-03-01  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- rprojroot     1.3-2    2018-01-03  CRAN (R 3.5.0)
- rstudioapi    0.11     2020-02-07  CRAN (R 3.6.2)
- sessioninfo   1.1.1    2018-11-05  CRAN (R 3.5.1)
- testthat      2.3.2    2020-03-02  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- usethis       1.6.0    2020-04-09  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- vctrs         0.2.4    2020-03-10  CRAN (R 3.6.3)
- withr         2.1.2    2018-03-15  CRAN (R 3.5.0)

[1] D:/R_HOME/library
[2] D:/R_HOME/R-3.6.3/library
```

#### Reproducible Code

```
library(DBI)

#Connect to MySQL database
con  <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
            dsn =mydsn, 
            database = mydatabase, 
            uid=myId, 
            pwd= myPassword)

dbListTables(con)

x <- dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars, temporary = FALSE)

dbReadTable(con, "mtcars")

x2 <- dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars[2:3, ], append=TRUE, temporary = FALSE)

dbReadTable(con, "mtcars")

dbListTables(con)
dbExistsTable(con, "mtcars")

dbDisconnect(con)
```

After 
`x <- dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars, temporary = FALSE)` 
x = TRUE

After the following 
`dbReadTable(con, "mtcars")`

The output is:

`row_names   mpg cyl disp  hp   drat   wt    qsec   vs am  gear carb`

`1 Mazda RX4  21   6  160   110  3.9   2.62   16.46  0   1    4    4`

After 
`x2 <- dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars[2:3, ], append=TRUE, temporary = FALSE)`
 
x2 = TRUE

After the following 
`dbReadTable(con, "mtcars")`

The output is:

`row_names       mpg cyl disp  hp   drat   wt    qsec   vs am  gear carb`

`1 Mazda RX4      21   6  160   110  3.9   2.62   16.46  0   1    4    4`

`2 Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160   110  3.9   2.875  17.02  0   1    4    4`

The problem appears so basic and I have uninstalled and reinstalled R, RStudio and DBI, odbc,  as well as, any other package that I thought might depend on those, but I have had no success. All packages are up to date.

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

MySQL Workbench 8.0 version 8.0.19

MySQL Workbench 8.0 version 8.0.19 Build 15713499 CE (64 bits) Community

Windows 10 Pro 64-bit  Version: 18362.720

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz

System Memory 16GB

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use `RMariaDB::MariaDB()` in place of `odbc::odbc()`? The drivers should be interchangeable, but I can't see any other issues at first glance.

Comment: @Brian I tried to use RMariaDB::MariaDB() but I kept getting an error message concerning "caching-sha2-password" and I have't figured out how to resolve that problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

@Brian Thank you very much for your suggestion.  It took a while to get RMariaDB to communicate with MySQL without giving the caching_sha2_password error, but RMariaDB was finally able to connect and dbWriteTable was successfully able to write the full data.frames to MySQL. It appears the problem must be odbc.

Comment: I'm about to embark on a similar journey, if you can provide details on how to avoid the caching_sha2_password error that would be very much appreciated. Maybe post the working version of your reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I worked around the caching_sha2_password error.

First, I opened     C:/~/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/my.ini  in Notepad++.

Then I changed the following line:
from:   default_authentication_plugin= caching_sha2_password
to:     default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
and saved it.

Then I ran:
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

The results showed 'newuser'@'localhost' had all privileges.

I tested it and it was successful.